# auth0 checkSession({}) returns login_required when logged in through social provider, but not when logging in via username/password

Tags: auth0

I have an Angular app that uses Auth0 for authentication, and I'm trying to use checkSession({}, …) to persist a user's session if the token hasn't expired yet.

When I log in with my username/pw that I set up for the site, this works fine when I reload the browser/navigate directly to a resource. However, when I log in using a social provider (such as Google), the checkSession({}, …) call on a page reload returns an error and forces the user to log in again.

Some of the relevant code (mostly from the auth0 tutorial(s)):

```
    export class AuthService {
  // Create Auth0 web auth instance
  private _auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_ID,
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_DOMAIN,
    responseType: 'token',
    redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.REDIRECT,
    audience: AUTH_CONFIG.AUDIENCE,
    scope: AUTH_CONFIG.SCOPE
  });
  accessToken: string;
  userProfile: any;
  expiresAt: number;
  // Create a stream of logged in status to communicate throughout app
  loggedIn: boolean;
  loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.loggedIn);
  loggingIn: boolean;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  
  // Subscribe to token expiration stream
  refreshSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // If app auth token is not expired, request new token
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at')) > Date.now()) {
      this.renewToken();
    }
  }

...
  handleAuth() {
    // When Auth0 hash parsed, get profile
    this._auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this._getProfile(authResult);
      } else if (err) {
        this._clearRedirect();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        console.error(`Error authenticating: ${err.error}`);
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }

  private _getProfile(authResult) {
    this.loggingIn = true;
    // Use access token to retrieve user's profile and set session
    this._auth0.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, (err, profile) => {
      if (profile) {
        this._setSession(authResult, profile);
        this._redirect();
      } else if (err) {
        console.warn(`Error retrieving profile: ${err.error}`);
      }
    });
  }

  private _setSession(authResult, profile?) {
    this.expiresAt = (authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + Date.now();
    // Store expiration in local storage to access in constructor
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', JSON.stringify(this.expiresAt));
    this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
    this.userProfile = profile;  
    
    if (profile) {
      this.isAdmin = this._checkAdmin(profile);
    }
    
    ...
  }
  
  
  ...

  get tokenValid(): boolean {
    // Check if current time is past access token's expiration
    return Date.now() < JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
  }

  renewToken() {
    // Check for valid Auth0 session
    this._auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
        this._getProfile(authResult);
      } else {
        this._clearExpiration();
      }
    });
  }
   

}
```

(This is from a service that is called in many places within the app, including some route guards and within some components that rely on profile information. If more of the app code would be useful, I can provide it.)

Also note: AUTH_CONFIG.SCOPE = 'openid profile email'

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue appears to not have been related to my app at all. When using Social Providers, Auth0 has an explicit note in one of their tutorials that really helped me out:

The issue with social providers is that they were incorrectly configured in my Auth0 dashboard, and needed to use provider-specific app keys.

> Important Note: If you are using Auth0 social connections in your app,
> please make sure that you have set the connections up to use your own
> client app keys. If you're using Auth0 dev keys, token renewal will
> always return login_required. Each social connection's details has a
> link with explicit instructions on how to acquire your own key for the
> particular IdP.

Comment was found on this page: https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-7/

Comment: Hi Justin, Hope you are doing good. I am stuck with the same issue. Can you please help me out here? So in my case, I am using Google for social signing in and when authorizing & checking the session back, do I have to use the clientID from the Google App or the Auth0 app? I am able to authorize but it failed on checkSession method